# Error finishing importing Nominatim: idx_word_word_id?

Tags: import, nominatim

After three weeks of hard work, I was one step from the end of importing planet.osm, but it crashed!

This is the first log error:

```
user@maps:~/Nominatim$ tail setup.log
  Done 37133684 in 148141 @ 250.664459 per second - Rank 30 ETA (seconds): -2.309861
  Done 37133685 in 148142 @ 250.662766 per second - ETA (seconds): -2.313866
  Done 37134058 in 151624 @ 244.908829 per second - ETA (seconds): -3.891244
  Done 37134058 in 151624 @ 244.908829 per second - FINISHED                    

Search indices
CREATE INDEX
connection to server was lost
ERROR: pgsql returned with error code (2)
pgsql returned with error code (2)
```

Then I restarted it with the comand written in the wiki, and then I got this:
    user@maps:~/Nominatim$ tail setup1.log
    Starting rank 29
      Done 0 in 0 @ 0.000000 per second - FINISHED

```
Starting rank 30
  Done 0 in 0 @ 0.000000 per second - FINISHED

Search indices
ERROR:  relation "idx_word_word_id" already exists
ERROR: pgsql returned with error code (3)
pgsql returned with error code (3)
```

and I obtain it everytime I use that command to resume the indexing. Don't tell me I do have to re-do everything from the beginning!

I use a Ubuntu 14.04.1 with the last PostGIS, PostgreeSQL, etc...

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

connect to PostgreSQL via

```
pgsql nominatim
```

then, inside use this command

```
drop index idx_word_word_id;
```

then quit via

```
\q
```

and restart the indexing as specified by the guide. Simple as that!